# Codeigniter Custom pagination url using Route and Constant file

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to customize my codeigniter pagination url,
'http://www.domanin.com/products.html' this url is working fine but when i go to page 2 which is 'http://www.domanin.com/products.html/2' i am getting page not found.

by default codeigniter provide this url

> www.domanin.com/controller/method/pageno

I want it to be something like this

> http://www.domanin.com/products.html for page 1 and

for page 2 i want it something like this

> http://www.domanin.com/products.html/2

I am using constant.php and Route.php file for routing.
Constant.php file code

```
define('PRODUCTS', 'products.html');
```

Route.php file code

```
$route[PRODUCTS] = 'ProductsController/index';
```

ProductsController.php file code

```
   $this->load->library('pagination');
   $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
   $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url('products.html'),
        'per_page' => 3,
        'total_rows' => $this->model->getAllProductsCount(),
    ];

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); // model function
    $template['campaigns'] = $this->model->getAllProducts($config['per_page'],$page);
```

I have tried to found solution on SO and there are lots of solution for pagination but none of them helped me.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Are there any errors? What is the result you get by this code? Please specify

Comment: @sauhardnc updated my question with the error what i am getting

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update your routing since you're manually defining the `route` for this `URL`.

**routes.php**

```
$route[PRODUCTS]           = 'ProductsController/index';
$route[PRODUCTS.'/(:num)'] = 'ProductsController/index';
```

The code above tells the `server` that if there is any number after `products.html(PRODUCTS)`, you need not look for it but instead reroute it to the `index function` of `ProductsController controller`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: After Using this i am getting 
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected ':' 
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\application\config\routes.php

Line Number: 408

Comment: I've updated the answer, `PRODUCTS` is constant so you don't need it to enclosed within quotes but same is not true for `/(:num)`, so you'll have to concatenate it. I think that might be causing the error